# Making changes to the shared library

Tags: linux, c, shared-library, dynamic-linking

Suppose we have a C program that uses the shared library.

If you make changes to a shared library and rebuild it, all programs using that library will automatically receive those changes the next time they run. In the case of a static library, the changes become visible only after the program is recompiled with the new version of the library.

If we change the code of some shared library functions (without changing method signatures), add new functions, etc., the addresses of the functions will change.

How will a program that uses our shared library find these functions again without recompiling and relinking? If their addresses have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the the existing answers: your executable uses the dynamic loader to find the shared library .so file, executes its initialization function, and gets the table of *symbols* (i.e., function names/mangled signatures) that contains the function addresses. It then changes the values of the function pointers that your linker step used whenever you used a function from a shared library.

So, the trick is that your program never used a fixed address to use these functions – it had a list of function pointers with yet-undefined addresses, and the dynamic linker at run time fills in the actual addresses of the functions from the library itself.

Comment: So dynamic loader is called every time we run a program that uses a shared library?

Comment: Sure: dynamic loader is built into your executable. Create a `Hello, World` executable and run it under `strace` to see the system calls.

Answer (score 1):

In the header of shared libraries there is a table which contain the name of function and address. So when main program want to call the function it look in to this table and jump to the address (with appropriate parameters if required)

Answer (score 1):

`.so` as any library keeps a list of which functions it exports and where they are.

So, broadly speaking, then a program wants a function from the shared library a multi step process happening - read list of exported names, find the function name, get an address for it, read `.so` file at that address.

If you want to find these addresses yourself, you can start reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format